# API Gmail : renturns error "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, gmail-api

the code available at : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python
asks to create the content of the e-mail encoded as base64url string, and offers the following code :

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

So, when sending :

```
def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
```

the returned message :
"Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"

Thanks for your help

bob2fox

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 2):

### There is some error in the documentation

[base64.urlsafe_b64encode(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) expects bytes and not strings.

Replace

```py
{'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

with

```py
{'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

Comment: Thank you ziganotschka

Comment: I suppose I have to replace body={... by return {...

Comment: In your case -yes -sorry for the confusion!